# How to target Android < 3.0 User Agent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

How can I specifically `target Android < 3.0` in either vanilla JS or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var start = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android ");
var majorversion = navigator.userAgent.substr(start+8,1)
if (majorversion < 3) { .... }
```

Regex would also work, actually regex would be better since this code won't work when there is an Android version 10, 11... etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to detect available features instead of specific browser / OS versions. You can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for this.

If you really need to detect Android < 3.0, as [NoBugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266581/how-to-target-android-3-0-user-agent-in-javascript#answer-11266730) says it's better to use a regexp:

```
var majorversion = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android (\d+)\./i);
var isoldandroid = (majorversion != null && parseInt(majorversion[1]) < 3);
if (isoldandroid) { ... }
```